# Adding a cordova plugin via ssh url results in wrong username

Tags: git, cordova, plugins, bitbucket

I want to add my cordova plugin which is in a private bitbucket repo. Therefore I want to use the SSH url which is the following:

```
myuser@bitbucket.org:myuser/cordova-plugin-xyz.git
```

As you can see the user is myuser.

If I now run

```
cordova plugin add git+ssh://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/cordova-plugin-xyz.git
```

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! Command failed: git clone
>   --template=/home/localuser/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror 
>           ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myuser/cordova-plugin-xyz.git 
>           /home/localuser/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-myuser-cordova-plugin-xyz-git-160b6243
>           npm ERR! Klone in Bare-Repository 
>           '/home/localuser/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-bitbucket-org-myuser-cordova-plugin-xyz-git-160b6243' 
>           ...
>           npm ERR! repository access denied.
>           npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

As you can see cordova tries to get the plugin by the url

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myuser/cordova-plugin-xyz.git
```

which sets `git` as user which is wrong in my case.

Is there any way to change the user cordova uses? Is this a bug? Can I switch something in bitbucket so that it accepts the git user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name part of the SSH URL doesn't really matter on Bitbucket - both "git" and your username should work, though the username is a tiny bit faster. You can confirm this by running `ssh -v username@bitbucket.org` and `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org`, which should have the same output for both.

That particular error could mean that Cordova isn't getting to Bitbucket, or that it isn't using a private key that permits access to that repo. If you run `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` from that system and user, does it establish the connection and mention your username?

Comment: Ah, now I see: The problem is that I have multiple SSH keys for BitBucket for multiple accounts. Now the problem is that the cordova cli tool uses git (seems to be hardcoded :-( ) and this user is linked to the wrong account. Changing this link isn't possible. Also I tried to create a "config" file in ~/.ssh and vary the host (as described here https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/ ) which also doesn't work (cordova cli tool says unsupported URL format). Unless there's no way to tell the cordova cli tool not to take "git" user I'm screwed.

Comment: You should probably re-read my answer: it does not matter whether the SSH command uses "git" or a real username, as long as the SSH key being used is associated with a user that has permissions. You can confirm this by running ssh -v username@bitbucket.org and ssh -v git@bitbucket.org, which should have the same output for both.

Comment: I understood. But as I wrote, I have loaded *two* ssh keys at the same time because I need to checkout from two different accounts at 1 computer. Hence the two commands haven‘t got the same output.